# R Shiny and highcharter - How to define size and location of 3 plots

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

I'm new to the R Shiny/ highcharter domain, so any help would be great! I've also poked around the forum and the internet, but I haven't come across anything that directly pertains to my request.

In short, I'm looking to build an R Shiny web app that comes with an interactive UI and 3-4 dynamic graphs/plots that all fits on one page. I have a general sense in how to build the UI portion, but I am confused with how to implement the framework to include 3-4 graphs - specifically, I'd love it if I were able to have a main graph taking up a majority of the space, with 2-3 graphs below and to the right of the main graph, and the interactive UI to the left of the main graph. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use `columns`. But first you should show us your code,...

Comment: I would try out something small first, and then if you can't get what you want, post it here with that code.  Laying out graphs can be tricky.

Comment: which library should I start off with first, or is it possible with base code?

Comment: I found a tutorial on building the layout: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html 
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!